# what is the maximum job execution time of onHandleWork() of JobIntentService?

Tags: android

I am encountering a `SecurityException` crash on Android 8 with `targetSDK 26` when using `JobIntentService`.

This is from JobIntentService docs:

[image]

So What is the maximumJobExecution time limit - and if we exceed it - will it possible that a SecurityException will be thrown?

[Security Exception issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293)

Cheers

Comment: "What is the maximumJobExecution time limit" -- 10 minutes, hard-coded into the `JobService` implementation, at least for Android 8.x. "if we exceed it - will it possible that a SecurityException will be thrown?" -- those issues don't seem to be caused by exceeding the 10-minute limit. However, I have not tested to see exactly what happens if you try running past 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've manually tested it, the maximum execution time is `600` seconds, which means `10`minutes. What happens next, is the `JobIntentService` gets destroyed, then re-created to resume the rest of the work. This has been tested from Android `Marshmallow` to Android `Oreo` . I also haven't experienced any thrown exception, I'm also using `Thread.sleep()` method to simulate a long process.

**Update 1**:
I've noticed, that after a while the service stops or Android puts it to sleep. So let's say, you're doing constant checks in the background i.e. API calls to get latest data to push notifications. It works for a while, then stops after a day or 2. I'm not sure why it randomly stops.

Comment: Thanks for your test but I believe we do not want experiments results (outdated already) but hard facts.

Answer (score 0):

No part of specification says what is that time.

So it, most likely, depends on device and/or SDK.

What specification DOES say is
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService#onStopCurrentWork()

> This will be called if the JobScheduler has decided to stop this job.

So you can hook up to the moment when it happens.