# Not allowed to start service Intent from background

Tags: android, android-intent

In our Application class in onCreate we have following code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();    
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
                            && ((PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.getPackageName())) {
      final Intent pendingIntent= new Intent(context, ScheduledUpdateService.class);
      startService(pendingIntent);
  }
}
}
```

On the line "startService()" we get many crashes according to Firebase Crashyltics:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { ... PairActivityUserId=11 }: app is in background uid UidRecord{3ec0561 u11a247 SVC  idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1538)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1484)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:663)
       at com.myapp.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:30)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6062)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Until now it happens on Android 8 and 9 on different devices (Samsung, Lenovo, ZTE, etc.)
Shouldn't that check be enough to start an intent from the background? Any hints?

Comment: "In Our Application class in onCreate we have following code" -- why? Only start a service when it will be actively delivering value to the user. Starting a service just because the OS forks a process for you does not seem like a good plan. Beyond that, [the documentation on background execution limits on Android 8.0+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) covers what you are seeing.

Comment: We start a service to do some work each time the app starts, but that's another topic beyond the issue.

Comment: Can you share your manifest ?  Do you use?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

Comment: We do use that permission in our app.

Comment: can you change startService() with startForegroundService() not sure, maybe it helps

Comment: No, it's a background service for now.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 8+, if an app is running in background, it's not allowed to start a service in background. Android asks us to start the service explicitly by content.startForegroundService instead of context.startService and when the service is started within 5 seconds it must be tied to the notification to have a UI element associated with it.

If you really need to start the service everytime your activity is created, you might be interested in `android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService`

This type of service is used to execute short tasks in the background of your app.

You must publish your `JobIntentService` subclass in your manifest for the OS to interact with.  It should be published as a JobService i.e. include the `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE` permission, since on Android 8 and later platforms it will be executed that way.

```
 <service
    android:name=".YourJobService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

You can find more info about `JobIntentService` here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService

Comment: Not necessarely, JobIntentService is recommended instead of an IntentService, but in this case we are using a normal Service which start the task in a ThreadPoolExecutor. Anyways, the issue should be independent from this I think, mabye it's only a bug/bad implementation on some devices, since for example in the case of Samsung we have reports only from S7 and a Galaxy Tab but none newer ones like S8-S9-S10.

Comment: It's allowed to start a background service if the app is whitelisted from battery optimization, that's the reasson of the check isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()

Comment: This check does not make your app whitelisted. Again, if you don't want to use a foreground service, use JobIntentService. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57464381/2068732

Comment: isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations() CHECKS if the app is whitelisted, I never said it adds it to the whitelist.

Comment: As of today I think the assumption that an app can start a service from the background if being whitelisted was wrong and we still need to dig into it to find the solution.